# Devise Mailer, using custom email template for existing module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using ruby on rails, with devise.

I have a senario wherin an Administrator would be able to add new user to the web application giving his email id and under this senario i'd be creating a new user. and would like to issue an Auth-Token to the user email. so when he clicks the link in his email, he'd be prompted to issue his/her new password.

My forgot password implementation.

```
def create
    resource = User.send_reset_password_instructions(params[:user])
    if successfully_sent?(resource)
      render json: {status: :true},status: 200
    else
      render json: {status: :false, error: user.errors.full_messages.join(",")   } , status: 200
    end
  end
```

Now my question is how do i use the same logic as that of forgot password, but use different Email-template for the user-added by the administrator screen. ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you redirecting a user to forgot your password page when you can simply redirect him/her to settings page from where a user can change his/her password?

Create a mailer action with its template and simply call that mailer action inside the method where your admin is creating users. e.g:

if your mailer action is:

```
def forgot_pass(email)
  mail(to: email, subject: 'Change your pass')
end
```

and your method where your admin is creating users is:

```
def create_user
  # your logic
  YourMailerClass.forgot_pass(xyz@abc.com).deliver
end
```

For more details on mailer refer to [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

Comment: forgot password and admin may have different email-template is what i'm saying. but the functionality remains same.

Comment: @RonakJain You want to have a different forgot password template for normal users and the users added by admin?